# Implement face authentication in React App

Tags: reactjs, basic-authentication, webauthn, windows-hello

I wanted to create a React Application that could be unlocked via Face Authentication similar to Windows Hello. How does face authentication work? How can I make this work? Many android applications and iOS applications already have this functionality. Is there any website implementing such functionality?

Comment: Given you've tagged webauthn on this question can you expland on how far you've looked into it? BTW the short answer is "yes you can do this using webauthn/FIDO2 provided the device you're using has a platform authenticator that can use your face".

Comment: I read about two tech U2F and UAF. Based on my understanding U2F is supported by desktop. Is it the same thing used for Face Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

The WebAuthn API and FIDO2/CTAP2 spec is supported on all major platforms/browsers now, including iOS, Android and Windows 10 (Hello). This means you can implement a similar experience to native iOS apps in a browser application if you wish as well as supporting FIDO compliant security keys also.

You can try it for yourself here: https://webauthn.io/

You'd need a backend that can support registration of credentials and authentication of assertions however. This is potentially non-trivial depending on what you have in play but library support is improving all the time.

Comment: Is there any equivalent of Windows Hello on MacOS?

Comment: Not my area of expertise but you can certainly use WebAuthn in Safari and use the touchbar fingerprint reader on a Macbook for example.